# How can I output different data from each line?

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have the following file:

```
File: ‘./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.10_2022_11_14_06_24_49.xml’
Modify: 2022-11-14 06:24:54.466847421 -0500
Change: 2022-11-14 06:25:02.166883414 -0500
  File: ‘./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.9_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml’
Modify: 2022-11-14 06:24:54.740847211 -0500
Change: 2022-11-14 06:25:02.166883414 -0500
  File: ‘./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml’
Modify: 2022-11-14 06:24:54.637847290 -0500
Change: 2022-11-14 06:25:02.166883414 -0500
```

I want the output to look like this for each file:

```
Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.10_2022_11_14_06_24_49.xml
06:24:54
06:25:02
```

If possible, at the end I want to make the difference between the two hours displayed (Change-Modify)

```
Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.10_2022_11_14_06_24_49.xml
00:00:08
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and GNU `date` command:

```
while read -r attr data; do
    [[ $attr == File: ]] && echo "$data"
    [[ $attr == Modify: ]] && m="$data"
    if [[ $attr == Change: ]]; then
        c="$data"
        c_epoch=$(date -d"$c" +%s)
        m_epoch=$(date -d"$m" +%s)
        echo "$((c_epoch - m_epoch)) seconds"
     fi
done < file
```

### Output:

```
‘./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.10_2022_11_14_06_24_49.xml’
8 seconds
‘./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.9_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml’
8 seconds
‘./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml’
8 seconds
```

Answer (score 3):

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

INPUT_FILENAME="$1"

while read -r FIELD_NAME DATA; do
    # echo "REPLY=<$REPLY>"
    case "${FIELD_NAME}" in
        "File:")
            # Get only text between ‘ and ’
            FILE="${DATA#*‘}"
            FILE="${FILE%’*}"
            # Print filename
            printf "%s\n" "$FILE"
        ;;
        "Modify:")
            DATE_MODIFY="${DATA}"
            # Print date
            DATE_MODIFY_PRINT="${DATE_MODIFY#* }"
            DATE_MODIFY_PRINT="${DATE_MODIFY_PRINT%.*}"
            printf "%s\n" "${DATE_MODIFY_PRINT}"
            # Compute seconds since 01/01/1970
            SECONDS_MODIFY=$(date --date "${DATE_MODIFY}" +%s)
        ;;
        "Change:")
            DATE_CHANGE="${DATA}"
            # Print date
            DATE_CHANGE_PRINT="${DATE_CHANGE#* }"
            DATE_CHANGE_PRINT="${DATE_CHANGE_PRINT%.*}"
            printf "%s\n" "${DATE_CHANGE_PRINT}"
            # Compute seconds since 01/01/1970
            SECONDS_CHANGE=$(date --date "${DATE_CHANGE}" +%s)
            # Compute hours, minutes and seconds between two dates (assume CHANGE >= MODIFY)
            SECONDS_DIFF=$(( SECONDS_CHANGE - SECONDS_MODIFY ))
            MINUTES_DIFF=$(( SECONDS_DIFF / 60 ))
            SECONDS_DIFF=$(( SECONDS_DIFF - ( MINUTES_DIFF * 60 ) ))
            HOURS_DIFF=$(( MINUTES_DIFF / 60 ))
            MINUTES_DIFF=$(( MINUTES_DIFF - ( HOURS_DIFF * 60 ) ))
            printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" "$HOURS_DIFF" "$MINUTES_DIFF" "$SECONDS_DIFF"
        ;;
    esac
done < <(cat "${INPUT_FILENAME}"; echo)
```

Output:

```
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.10_2022_11_14_06_24_49.xml
06:24:54
06:25:02
00:00:08
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.9_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml
06:24:54
06:25:02
00:00:08
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml
06:24:54
07:28:02
00:00:08
```

Comment: Good point using case statement, but the UPPERCASE variables naming are not a good idea, because you take a risk of collision with system wide variables

Answer (score 3):

Using perl and the [Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Format) and [Time::Duration](https://metacpan.org/release/Time-Duration) modules.  `Date::Parse` is a module for parsing dates into the unix `time_t` seconds-since-the-epoch (Midnight, Jan 1 1970) format, and `Time::Duration` is a module for printing seconds as an English expression.   Neither of these are included with perl, they'll need to be installed via [cpan](https://perldoc.perl.org/CPAN) or from a distro package (e.g. on Debian: `apt-get install libtimedate-perl libtime-duration-perl`)

```
$ perl -MDate::Parse -MTime::Duration -lne '
  if (/^\s*File:\s*/) {
    s/^.*?: //; # remove field name
    s/^‘|’$//g; # remove quotes
    print;

  } elsif (/^\s*Modify:\s*/) {
    s/^.*?: //;
    $mod = $_;

  } elsif (/^\s*Change:\s*/) {
    s/^.*?: //;
    $change = $_;
    print duration_exact(str2time($change) - str2time($mod));
  }' file.txt
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.10_2022_11_14_06_24_49.xml
7 seconds
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.9_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml
7 seconds
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml
7 seconds
```

This output is nothing surprising (except that the seconds are rounded *down* - you could use `int(str2time($change) - str2time($mod) + 0.5)` if you wanted it rounded to the *nearest* second, or add `BEGIN {$Time::Duration::MILLISECOND=1};` to the start of the script to enable millisecond mode and round to the nearest millisecond), but the Time::Duration module really shows its value with larger time intervals between the Modify and Change timestamps.  For example, if the last Change time in `file.txt` was:

```
Change: 2022-11-18 09:25:02.166883414 -0500
```

Then the output for that file would be:

```
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml
4 days, 3 hours, and 7 seconds
```

and, if the Change timestamp was:

```
Change: 2029-11-18 09:25:02.166883414 -0500
```

then the output would be:

```
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml
7 years, 6 days, 3 hours, and 7 seconds
```

Which is a lot more comprehensible than `221281207.529036` seconds.

Or, if the script used Time::Duration's `duration()` function rather than `duration_exact()`, it would round off the least significant parts of the duration (with "significance" varying according to the scale of the duration):

```
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.10_2022_11_14_06_24_49.xml
7 seconds
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2.9_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml
7 seconds
./Payment_Volume_and_Value_Report_000000501C5_2022_11_14_06_24_54.xml
7 years and 6 days
```

Hours, Minutes, and Seconds are still considered "significant" for short durations, but not significant for long durations.