# Extract UTC time and find difference

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with the following sample records for buy and sell events

```
Buy at time=Thu Aug 03 2023 14:13:08 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

Sell-at time=Thu Aug 03 2023 14:53:02 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

I want to get whole UTC string from all the lines and get time difference between these records, however, i am not able to extract whole date time string to get differnce between them. i have tried this but not able to get time. Can any one help me out.

```
while read line
do
    name=$line

    echo $name | sed -e 's/time=\(.*\)(Central/\1/'

done < $1
```

Solution using shell, awk or sed is required. i can also use GNU date if required

Comment: Will the two times ever be in different time zones (e.g., when switching to daylight saving time)?

Comment: No, they all are for same time zone.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add i) your operating system, and whether we can assume you can use GNU tools, especially GNU `date` (the default on Linux systems) and ii) the _exact_ output you would like to see from your example input. Can you also clarify why you can only use those three specific tools? Would a Perl one liner not be acceptable, for instance?

Comment: Related - [Bash: calculate the time elapsed between two timestamps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/387012/100397)

Comment: What's a *UTC string*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dconv` of dateutils (called `dateutils.dconv` on Debian-derived systems) has a `sed` mode to convert dates. So you could convert your timestamps to epoch time with it and `awk` to print differences between Sell and Buy dates in seconds:

```bash
dateutils.dconv -SE -i ' time=%a %b %d %Y %T GMT%Z' -f '=%s=' < your-file |
  awk -F= '$1 == "Buy at"  {buy = $2; next}
           $1 == "Sell-at" {print $2 - buy}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Bash and GNU/date.

This cuts off the unwanted parts of the date, and then converts a date to epoch (seconds since 01-Jan-1970).

```
$ Sell='Sell-at time=Thu Aug 03 2023 14:53:02 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)'
$ declare -p Sell
declare -- Sell="Sell-at time=Thu Aug 03 2023 14:53:02 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)"
$ Sell="${Sell/ (*/}"
$ declare -p Sell
declare -- Sell="Sell-at time=Thu Aug 03 2023 14:53:02 GMT+0200"
$ Sell="${Sell/*=}"
$ declare -p Sell
declare -- Sell="Thu Aug 03 2023 14:53:02 GMT+0200"
$ Sell=$( date -d "${Sell}" '+%s' )
$ declare -p Sell
declare -- Sell="1691067182"
$ date -d "@${Sell}"  #.. Check correctness (in UK time).
Thu  3 Aug 13:53:02 BST 2023
```

Do the same for Buy (maybe declare a function to use twice), and subtract to get the difference in seconds.

Comment: Using `Sell="${Sell% (*}"; Sell="${Sell#*=}"` instead of ksh93-style `${Sell/pattern}`  would make it standard `sh` syntax and remove the need to install bash or other ksh93-like shell.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Very true. I suspect I was thinking in `awk sub()` and converting that to Bash. Past my bed-time, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How can I output different data from each line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724968/how-can-i-output-different-data-from-each-line/724995#724995)

You need bash and GNU date command.

With `./data-diff-records.sh` script:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

declare -r input_filename="$1"

function get_date () {
    local -r -n l_str="$1"
    local -n li_date="$2"
    local l_date="${l_str#*time=}"
    l_date="${l_date% (Central *}"
    # date transformation to seconds since 1st January 1970
    li_date=$(date -d "$l_date" +'%s')
    # printf "date=<%s>=>%d\n" "$l_date" "$li_date"
}

function diff_date () {
    local -r -n l_start_date="$1"
    local -r -n l_end_date="$2"
    local -n l_seconds_diff="$3"
    local -n l_minutes_diff="$4"
    local -n l_hours_diff="$5"
    l_seconds_diff=$(( l_end_date - l_start_date ))
    l_minutes_diff=$(( l_seconds_diff / 60 ))
    l_seconds_diff=$(( l_seconds_diff - ( l_minutes_diff * 60 ) ))
    l_hours_diff=$(( l_minutes_diff / 60 ))
    l_minutes_diff=$(( l_minutes_diff - ( l_hours_diff * 60 ) ))
}

declare -i date_buy=0
declare -i date_sell=0
declare -i seconds_diff=0
declare -i minutes_diff=0
declare -i hours_diff=0
while read -r line; do
    first_token="${line%% *}"
    case "$first_token" in
        "Buy")
            get_date line date_buy
            # echo "first_token=<$first_token> date=<$date_buy>"
        ;;
        "Sell-at")
            get_date line date_sell
            # echo "first_token=<$first_token> date=<$date_sell>"
            diff_date date_buy date_sell seconds_diff minutes_diff hours_diff
            printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" "$hours_diff" "$minutes_diff" "$seconds_diff"
        ;;
    esac
done < "$input_filename"
```

and:

```bash
chmod +x ./data-diff-records.sh
```

Use it like this (where `records.log` is the input file):

```bash
./data-diff-records.sh records.log
```